# How to determine difference between NULL and the actual string "NULL" in a string column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to read values in mysql from a mysql database to be consumed downstream (eventually by a Ruby program parsing the stored results into typed values). When I encounter a varchar column, I sometimes see the value `NULL`. But I can't actually tell the difference between a db `NULL` and the actual string value `"NULL"`. While I don't expect a ton of strings with the value `"NULL"`, I don't want to assume and figure there has to be a way to determine which I'm actually getting back.

I'm doing this using `mysql -e $CMD`, but have also added the `-B` and `-r` flags, they do not present any difference that allows me to tell these two possible return values apart:

```
attribute1  attribute2
NULL    NULL
```

attribute2's value is the string `"NULL"`.

How can I tell these apart?

Comment: For Ruby I am not sure. But in PHP db NULL equals EMPTY. While a string NULL is NOT empty. Sample this will return FALSE: `if (!empty($attribute1))` and this will return TRUE for string: `if (!empty($attribute2))` this will return TRUE: `if (strlen($attribute2) === 4)`

Comment: This is only an issue when they're represented as text. They'll be obviously different in code where data types apply. Why do you have literal `"NULL"` in your data? That's usually a bug.

Comment: If you are attempting to parse a MySQL result set verbatim, you will not be able to tell the difference between the `NULL` value and the string "NULL". These values (and their types) will get set properly when you use a specific programmatic MySQL interface, e.g. PHP's PDO library.

Comment: It's arbitrary user data, so it's not my call if it's a bug or not. Trying to use the `mysql` command via the shell is a bit roundabout for sure, but it's an MVP for a data importing tool where it was easier to connect via a shell script so I got curious if this was possible.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz Can you adjust the `SELECT` statement and add a `attribute1 IS NULL` check?

Comment: @Progman that's a good idea, though in the general case will make for a very bulky query with a ton of bookkeeping since the intent is to be able to use this to import arbitrarily specified data from an arbitrarily specified table. It would work though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the constraint of using the `mysql` CLI, I got this working with the `-X` flag that at least my version supports. This outputs data in XML format, where the difference is represented in the output as

```
<resultset statement="select attribute1, attribute2 from media_files where id = 4000000
" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="attribute1" xsi:nil="true" />
    <field name="attribute2">NULL</field>
  </row>
</resultset>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to use any DBMS, only mysql CMD I see solution with conditionals representing columns.

```
SELECT IFNULL(NULL, '<<NULL>>'), IFNULL('NULL', "<<NULL>>"); --output <<NULL>> for NULL values
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, '<<NULL>>'), COALESCE('NULL', "<<NULL>>"); --output <<NULL>> for NULL values
```

or

```
SELECT IF(attribute1 = "NULL","\"NULL\"", attribute1); --output "NULL" for 'NULL' strings.
```

Of course you need to adjust queries to your columns.

```
SELECT COALESCE(attribute1, '<<NULL>>'), COALESCE(attribute2, "<<NULL>>") FROM ....;
```

Another way would be to just clear all `"NULL"` strings before SELECT query.

```
UPDATE table SET attribute2=NULL WHERE attribute2="NULL";
```

Comment: This assumes there are no existing values containing the string `"<<NULL>>"`.

Comment: That's exactly how this code works. It must be applied to OP's requirements which we don't know fully.